# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el umask para un usuario en el archivo ./bashrc?

Tags: linux, bash, permisos

Quiero modificar los permisos para un usuario con el comando `umask` pero no se si tengo que poner en el archivo `/bashrc` esto por ejemplo :

```
umask 022 díaz
```

Donde díaz es el usuario.

Comment: ¿No quisiste decir `umask` en lugar de `umak`?  Además, ¿A qué te refieres con darle permisos a un usuario? Eso podrías hacerlos desde su creación al asignarlo a ciertos grupos. Eso deberías de especificarlo en tu publicación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solución perezosa (lazy)

Añade el siguiente código al final del fichero `(/home/usuario/.bashrc)` del usuario en cuestión. Si el fichero no existe, lo puedes crear de cero:

```
umask 022
```

#### Explicación

Los SO no hacen distinción por usuario. Debes adoptar un atajo de personalización de usuario.

- Podrías editar el fichero `/etc/login.defs` y poner la mascara que tu quieras, pero se aplicará a **todos** los usuarios por igual. Solución no recomendada
- Podrías personalizar el fichero `pam_umask.so` del servicio PAM. Solución avanzada y tampoco recomendada.
- Editar los ficheros RC de la shell que vaya a utilizar el usuario en concreto. Solución propuesta

En programación muchas veces se usa el termino `lazy` / `perezos@` a la programación de una solución que, es funcional pero no recomendable. En tu caso, si te sirve adelante.

Sepa también:

- se pueden ejecutar aplicaciones con mascaras.
- el usuario puede modificar el `.bashrc`
- la configuración solo aplica a la `consola` que se use, si cambias por ejemplo a `zsh` deberás editar `.zshrc`